# AchartEngine line chart x-axis scale

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

I am using `AchartEngine` to create a line chart with multiple series. How do I make the x-axis non-linear?

As in, instead of having an x-axis of 2, 4, 6, 8, 10. I want it to go 2, 4, 8, 16, 32. I have tried using `x.add(new double[] { 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 });` but that just spreads out the plot points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

and

```
renderer.setXLabels(0);
renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "2");
renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "4");
renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "8");
renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "16");
renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "32");
```